# Getting the value of the selected radio button and insert the data

Tags: php, radio-button

I'm having a problem to my PHP/PostgreSQL coding. It's all about a voting system.
Here's what the code is:

```php
$queryCandidates = pg_query("Select * From candidate as can, positions as pos, partylist as par, election_date as elpe, course as cou Where pos.position_id = can.position_id And par.partylist_id = can.partylist_id And elpe.election_date_id = can.election_date_id And cou.course_id = can.course_id AND elpe.status = 'Started' ORDER BY pos.position_id ASC");
while($result = pg_fetch_array($queryCandidates, NULL, PGSQL_ASSOC))
{
echo '<tr><td class="positionTD">'.$result['position_name']. '</td><td><label><input type="radio" name="'.$result['position_name'].'" value="'.$result['candidate_id'].'"/> '.$result['firstname']. ' '. $result['lastname']. '<td>' .$result['candidate_id'].'</td></label></td></tr>';
            }
            echo '<tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit Votes" name="Submit"/></td></tr>';
```

Then this will display the voting form:

[image: Image 1]

In the voting system, you can only select one candidate in every position. But my **problem** is that, when the user clicks the "Submit Votes" button, the unchecked radio button is added to the database. So here is the code for the insertion of votes.

[image: Image 2]

```php
$queryVotes = pg_query("Select * From candidate");
while($result = pg_fetch_array($queryVotes, NULL, PGSQL_ASSOC))
{
$getVotes = pg_query("INSERT INTO vote (vote_id, candidate_id, voter_id) VALUES (default, '".$result['candidate_id']."', '".$_SESSION['voter_id']."')");
}
```

NOTE: The numbers you have seen beside the names are the primary keys of the candidate.

As you can see, I didn't select number "5". But in the PostgreSQL database, it was inserted even though I didn't checked it.

Comment: You're inserting a row for every candidate in the database and never checking whether the user checked the box or not...

Comment: Shouldn't this be checkbox instead of radio button? Radio button is meant to be used for single option selection.